# expected value of an absolute value random variable $E[|X|]$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

The question is:
Given $E[|X|]\le M$, for $M$ in real.
Prove $E[X]<\infty$ and $E[X]\ge -M$.
To be honest, I have no idea how to start, what I tried is by using definition, but got stuck:
$E[|X|] = E[X^+]-E[X^-]$.
The minus comes because of absolute value, such that: $$\left|X\right|=\begin{cases}X&X>0\\ -X&X\le 0\end{cases}$$
so:
$$E\left[\left|X\right|\right]=\int _0^{\infty }\left(1-F_X\left(t\right)\right)dt-\:\int _0^{\infty }\:F_X\left(-t\right)dt$$
And then, by using $t=-k$ and $dt=-dk$ we receive:
$$E\left[\left|X\right|\right]=\int _0^{\infty \:}\left(1-F_X\left(t\right)\right)-\int _{-\infty }^0\:F_X\left(t\right)dt$$
And from here sadly, I am stuck...
Thought maybe I can say that if the sum of integrals are bounded by $M$, as given, so of course the partial are also bounded and thus $E[X]<\infty$, I dont know if it is true, but still, I have trouble with the other one - $E[X]\ge -M$

**Any tip on how to continue please?**

Comment: I believe the usual definitions of $\ X^+\ $ and $\ X^-\ $ are
$$
X^+=\max(0,X)
$$
and
$$
X^-=\max(0,{-}X)\ ,
$$
 which gives $\ X=X^+\color{red}{-}X^-\ $, $\ |X|=X^+\color{red}{+}X^-\ $, with $\ X^+\ $ and $\  \ X^-\ $ both non-negative.  This makes it much easier to see how to go about proving the required results than with your implied definition of $\ X^-\ $, which requires it to be non-positive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks!! regarding what you said........... I dont really understand what you did with the absolute value of $|X|$ there, why is there a $+$ sign?       how is it possible that $X^-$ is non negative?

Comment: By definition the maximum of $\ 0\ $ and *anything* cannot be less than $\ 0\ $.  An equivalent definition of $\ X^-\ $ to that I gave (which, as I said, I believe to be the usual one) is $$X^-=\cases{-X&if $\ X<0$\\0&otherwise}\ ,$$ which makes it obvious that $\ X^-\ $ (thus defined) is positive when $\ X\ $ is negative and $\ 0\ $ when $\ X\ $ is non-negative.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X<|X|$, one has $E X \leq E |X|<\infty$. Moreover, $$E|X| = E X^++EX^- \leq M$$
, implying $E X^- \leq M$. Hence $$ E X = EX^+-EX^- \geq EX^+-M \geq- M$$
We conclude the stronger statement that $E X\geq -M$ with equality if and only if $X\leq 0$ almost surely.
Here, $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X,0)$

Comment: Hi, huge thanks for the answer, did not plan for this!!,,,,,,,,,,
Regarding the answer, a few questions please: .........
1. Oh I can say that the expected value is defined that easy? ...........
2. About implying $E[X^-]\le M$, this is what I said at my message, so I can say that if the sum of integrals are bounded, each part of the sum is bounded also? ( that is what you did, right? )...............
3. is the statement about almost surely really needed? It is a topic I barely understand to be honest. the inequality is not good enough?

Comment: 1) not sure what you mean 2) no, I am specifically using that the sum of two non-negative numbers is bounded by $M$ implies both are bounded by $M$ 3)just remarking the stronger statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, did not elaborate on 1, but I guess I understand........
Thank you very much, I understood all!!...... and last thing please, why $X\le 0$ is needed here? or it is not really needed? about the if and only if

Comment: I am saying that $E X = -M$ if and only if $X\leq 0$ almost surely. This follows from the inequality $E X^+-M  \geq -M$ which holds with equality if and only if $E X^+ = 0$, that is, $X\leq 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!!